# Is there a way to deal with "" in cells in an R dataframe, I would like to convert them to NA or delete them

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some data I'd like to clean and access the min and max values of some timestamps. The max values look fine, but when I filter for min values in my Dataframe, I get ""

To check what the value was, I ran a Boolean test and got, with the value names TimesNA

```
TimesNA == ""
[1] TRUE
> TimesNA == ''
[1] TRUE
```

My dataframe looks like this

```
  [53] ""                         ""                         ""                         ""                        
  [57] ""                         "Wed Dec  7 10:54:12 2022" "Wed Dec  7 10:54:14 2022" "Wed Dec  7 10:54:15 2022"
```

I'd like to either remove the "" values, or convert them to NAs
Has anyone experienced this issue before and know how to fix it? Thank you!

I have tried using gsub, but since the value is literally "", it's struggling to recognize it, as I don't think """" is going to work

`Times$LowWorkload_Single_Start <- gsub("''",'The R language',Times$LowWorkload_Single_Start)`, runs but when I look at the ouput, the "" values haven't been replaced by 'The R language'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When importing the data, for example using *read.table*, use `na.strings  = c("NA", "")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `na_if` function.

```r
library(tidyverse)

char <- c("A","","C")
val <- c(1:3)

df <- data.frame(char, val)

df %>%
  mutate(char= na_if(char, ""))
#>   char val
#> 1    A   1
#> 2 <NA>   2
#> 3    C   3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>